# Функция которая будет удалять значения из таблицы sql

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Помогите сделать функцию. Есть форма в нее вбивается число, допустим, `5432`, и в базе есть такое число

```
 INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `pin1` `pin2` ) 
        VALUES (1, '1616423598654365' '5432')
```

я уже сделал что при в воде идет запрос и проверяет есть ли такое число в бд или нет, после чего идет отправка на почту, а это число из базы должно удалиться и `pin1` и `pin2`

Comment: DELETE FROM users WHERE pin2=5432

Comment: вы, видимо, ничего не читали про [structured query language](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). почитайте.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM users 
  WHERE id = 1
```

или

```
DELETE FROM users 
  WHERE id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
public function trash($id, $field = '')
    {
        $field = $field ?: $this->pk;
        $sql = "DELETE FROM {$this->table} WHERE $field = ?";
        return $this->pdo->query($sql, [$id]);
    }
```